# Foreman: How to test if the deployment is on Bare Matal or in Libvirt?

Tags: libvirt, foreman, provisioning

I write a custom Kickstart as a Foreman provisioning template.
One of my problems is that I haven't found a way to determine if the new host will be installed on a bare metal or on a Hypervisor. 
The `@host.model` works on ESXi hypervisors, but Libvirt reports "Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)"

As a work around, I use this string as libvirt identifier, but, it's not safe and it's a workaround.

So, which parameter should I use to determine if the server will be a virtual one or not?

Answer (score 2):

This will check if the host is linked to a compute resource:

```
<% if @host.compute_resource -%>
virtual, on a compute resource
<% else -%>
physical, bare metal
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`virt-what(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-what) command to determine if you are on bare-metal or a virtualised environment.

Comment: Interesting. Is it available during kickstart? 
I will have to test it. I like that is a script-based solution so it's not binded with Ruby.